# how can I display a specific number of orders for a specific user?

Tags: odoo

How can I limit the number of orders for a specific user. For example if administrator see 320 orders, I wanna that a specific user see just 20 orders

[image]

Comment: question not explaining full scenario or case!! please explain bit more!

Comment: here I have just 2 orders (the post)  but for example if i have 200 or more I wanna that when a specific user log in be able to see just 20 orders

Comment: Based on what logic to limit the orders viewed by the specific user? Only orders belonging to them? Or only the most recent 20 orders? Or something else?

Comment: the most recent 20 orders